# How to install Windows.Security.Credentials; C# .NET VS 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

how do I install Windows.Security.Credentials into VS 2017? I've looked everywhere and i can't find a thing. I cant add it through 'add reference'.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hello! Wich class from Windows.Security.Credentials do you need?

Comment: Hey :D I need to access the PasswordVault

Answer (score 3):

Windows.Security.Credentials class avilible only in **WinRT** based projects type. For example in WindowsRuntimeComponent. You can't access to it from WinForms or Console project.